# Pass parent ng-template data to child ng-template

Tags: angular

Can we have one ng-template inside another ng-template.if its possible how to pass parent ng-template data to its child ng-template? I tried out a couple of different ways but nothing works for me.

```
 <ng-template let-r="result" #rt>
        {{r.categoryName}}
        <li *ngFor="let item of r.subCategoriesList">
          {{item}}
         </li>

     <ng-template>
       // i need get some data to this ng-templete from parent
    </ng-template>

</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<ng-template>` is a template definition. And e.g. `*ngTemplateOutlet` is a template instance. Template definition should not contain other definitions, but can contain templates instances, component instances etc. e.g.:

```
<div *ngTemplateOutlet="template1; context: {param: 'world'}" >

</div>

<ng-template #template1 let-param="param">
    <div *ngTemplateOutlet="template2; context: {param: param}" >

    </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #template2 let-param="param">
    Hello {{param}}
</ng-template>
```